# Entering a valid password

Tags: python

I want to make a function that checks for a valid password consisting of at least 1 uppercase letter, 1 lowercase letter, and at least 1 digit in Python. I would like the code to be on all one line, but I get an invalid syntax.

```
def password_check(password):
    return True ([if any(y.isupper() for y in password) and any(y.islower() for y in password) and (y.endswith(0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9) in password) else return False])
```

Comment: Hey Dan! Please accept the answer (by pressing tick on left of answer) if it's found helpful so future readers can easily get answer to their queries.

Answer (score 3):

You don't want to explicitly return a `True` or `False`. `any()`'s output is already a Boolean value.

```
def password_check(password):
    return any(y.isupper() for y in password) and any(y.islower() for y in password) and any(y.isdigit() for y in password)
```

**Sample run**:

```
>>> password_check('ahsjNcg4kg')
True
>>> password_check('ahsjcg4kg')
False
```